# Changing the periods in my file to exclamation points, and saving the full text to a new file

Tags: c

In a file I made, **practice.txt**, I have a few sentences that end with (`.`), I want to rewrite everything to a different file, but change all the periods to exclamation points.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("practice.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("practice_!.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return -1;

    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '.') {
            c = '!';
        }
        fputc(c, fp2);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't seem to be outputting anything to the new file.

Comment: Also test the write file `if ((fp == NULL) || (fp2 == NULL)) return -1;`

Comment: Maybe better: `if (fp == NULL) { perror("practice.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` and `if (fp2 == NULL) { perror("practice_!.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Answer (score 1):

You should test if both files wre open successfully and output a meaningful message if not. If your program fails to open the input file, it creates or truncates the output file and exits silently. This might explain be what you observe. Are you sure you run the program from the directory where the input file was created?

The copying and substitution code seems OK.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("practice.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n",
                "practice.txt", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("practice_!.txt", "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n",
                "practice_!.txt", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '.') {
            c = '!';
        }
        fputc(c, fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi can you elaborate a little bit on how to make sure the files are where they need to be? I haven't even considered that as a possible problem. I'm running the code straight out of my text editor's plugin.

Comment: You should run the program from a terminal window where you can ensure that the current directory contains the input file. Is the source code in the same directory? What system do you use? What editor?

Comment: I put all the files in my Documents. I am on Mac and am using Atom text editor, which has a plug in that automatically compiles and runs the code from terminal. I have honestly never directly ran code myself from terminal before.

Comment: Make sure the code is run from the `Documents` folder. There should be a setting or a command in the editor to configure the current directory for script execution. Otherwise you might provide the full path to the source and output files in the source code, but that should only be a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1):

You code is correct.

If the file was not opened, you'd get a segmentation fault since either fp or fp2 would then be NULL.

So... the only thing I can think of is that you're hunting a red herring.

Possibilities that come to mind:

- you're actually executing an old version of the executable file.
- you're on a Unix console (e.g. Linux), and you did not escape the "!" which is a shell special character. For example I managed to get this just now on my bash:

  ```
  $ cat practice_!.txt            # I should have enclosed the name in single quotes
  cat practice_.txt
  cat: practice_.txt: No such file or directory
  ```

(The file "practice_!.txt" does exist; "practice_.txt" does not).

Answer (score 1):

The Un*x way to write that program, is a [*filter*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(software)) (basically a program that reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '.') c = '!';
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and you'd use it as

```
executable <practice.txt >practice_!.txt
```